# Using Twinned Spell and Quickened Spell

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic, spellcasting

I am certain this must have been asked at some point - but most of the questions I have found pertaining to metamagic are quite specific.

My question is; 
**can I utilise the MM Twinned Spell, followed by the Quickened Spell?**

At 3rd level a sorcerer gets 3 SP.
What is to stop me applying 1 SP into Ray of Frost (using Twinned Spell) and then again using Quickened Spell - allowing for a double strike and a single strike against two targets (or 3 seperate-target attacks) ?